# Facebook javascript API: get username and image by session?

Tags: javascript, facebook

If i manage to get a response.session object, can i use it to get the current logged in users username and profile image?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
    var img_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture"
});
```

More info here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Answer (score 3):

Additionnaly, you can get more personnal informations about **connected** user :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                });
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Here are the three possible states:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and connected to your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user’s ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
//response.session contains what you lokks for
} else {
// user is not connected..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in and has authorized your application, you should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

After, you managed to get response session object, you can do following

```
            var rec="Name : "+response.name+"";
            rec +="Link: "+response.link+"";
            rec +="Username: "+response.username+"";
            rec +="id: "+response.id+"";
            rec +="Email: "+response.email+"";

            function getPhoto()
            {
            FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
            var img=response.data.url;
            });
```

For more info you can refer to this manual:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api